# US Trip in April 2012

Tags: usa, road-trips, itineraries

I'm planning a Southwest / Pacific trip during the first 15 days of April (more or less). I though to fly to San Francisco and, after a quick tour of the city (2 days?), rent a car and follow this way: Yosemite National Park, Sequoia National Park, Death Valley, Las Vegas, Bryce, Antelope, Monument Valley, Grand Canyon and back to Las Vegas to keep the return fly.

If I read enough about this area (really big), it's possible to found some road closed during this period and the temperature could be really cold at Yosemite and Sequoia. Is it correct? The problem is that we have our vacation period only in April, so, what do you suggest about this way? Is it possible to follow it during this period or will find bad weather conditions (like rain or cold)?

What should be the best US area to visit during the first mid of April?

Comment: What do you prefer?  Museums? Outdoors?

Comment: I prefer outdoors, I'm traveling with some guys that don't speak english so, visit museum could be hard and boring for them

Comment: Sounds like you are travelling right by [Zion National Park](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zion_National_Park) (between Las Vegas and Bryce).  If you have a chance, I would stop by.

Comment: @NickC good :) Added to my trip plan!

Comment: Ah, just for the record, the way from Las Vegas to Yosemite was closed due to a snow storm on april. But, I did it a very nice trip! Thanks to all for your replies!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think you'll have problems entering the Yosemite Valley in April. The road you'd be taking would probably be CA State Rte 99, which is clear any season and is one of the major California routes. CA 41 and CA 49 will probably be clear up to the valley, but crossing the range might be problematic (CA 120). Haven't been to Sequoia yet, but its similar to Yosemite weather wise.

You probably won't be able to climb the Half-Dome, or go to the Glacier Point, but you will still see the marvelous Yosemite Valley and it will be in its best.

All the rest shouldn't be a problem any time of the year.

Comment: As I recall, CA 120 usually doesn't reopen until May.  To cross the Sierras, you may have to go north to US 50 or I-80 or south to CA 58.

Answer (score 1):

If you do make it out to Las Vegas area I would recommend Red Rocks outside of the city it is worth the time. Beautiful area and you can drive thru it and also get out and stretch your legs thru part of it too.  You can see some neat petroglyphs that aren't to far off the road. it you don't make it that far make sure to visit the Golden Gate Bridge in San Francisco by at least walking across it near sunset or sunrise it is a great site to see.

Answer (score 1):

To check if a particular California highway is closed due to seasonal weather, use the [California Department of Transportation road conditions page](http://www.dot.ca.gov/cgi-bin/roads.cgi).